Retain Animation from Blender to RealityView
I've animated a cube but the animation goes missing when I bring the USD file into Reality Composer Pro or into my VisionOS project.
Here's my workflow:

Animate cube in Blender using SimpleDeform
Export as USD (with animation checked)
Convert it using Reality Converter

Other details:
When I look at the file with Quick View (space bar on Mac) the animation plays ✅
I wonder if the issue relates to SimpleDeform being used rather than more simple location, rotation keyframes.
You can download my animation file here.

There's no autoplay for animation in RealityKit. So you need to implement the playAnimation(..) method.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ae: AnimationResource? = nil

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            let animatedCube = try! await Entity(named: "plank")
            ae = animatedCube.availableAnimations[0].repeat()
            animatedCube.playAnimation(ae!)
            rvc.add(animatedCube)
        }
    }
}


Hi @MadDogCadogen, RealityKit doesn't play back keys' interpolation, it plays back a baked animation. The problem with your plank.usdz file is that the deformations you applied to a box in Blender are not recorded as a regular animation, which means that you'll not be able to play such a file in RealityKit (even though it plays in AR Quick Look). The list of availableAnimations associated with the entity is empty.

Thanks Andy, this is the issue I'm facing.
I've done a quick test replacing the bend animation with Blender's Armature animation. Essentially the bend comes from animating a skeleton within the cube rather than any key interpolation.
By exporting as USD and then running it through Reality Convertor, the animation is retained.
